# Login into Active Directory with PHP to perform CRUD operation on users?

Tags: php, active-directory

I enable ldap module in http.conf and enable ldap in php.ini
but without ldap Is there any way to access Active Directory with user login and CRUD operations with users and groups?

Suggest some tutorials or docs. This will much helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the builtin functions for the PHP LDAP module to do this:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php

Or you could use a LDAP library. I would suggest either:

- [LdapTools](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools) - Built around AD support. Lots of examples/docs.
- [AdLdap2](https://github.com/adldap2/adldap2) - A redesign of the adLDAP library, also lots of examples and docs.

Comment: Is there any library to use AD without LDAP?

Comment: No, AD is a Microsoft specific LDAP implementation.